# Deserialize nested JSON tags and attachments from Wordpress API JSON response

Tags: android, json, wordpress, retrofit2, gson

I am using Retrofit 2 in an Android app to communicate with [WordPress API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) but I have problems to get the attachments and tags from posts.

The corresponding JSON response looks like this:

```
{

"ID": 1,
"site_ID": 1,
"author": {
},
"tags": {
    "Doom": {
        "ID": 654,
        "name": "Doom",
        "slug": "doom",
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 53
    },
    "Ego-Shooter": {
        "ID": 73,
        "name": "Ego-Shooter",
        "slug": "ego-shooter",
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 724
    },
    "id Software": {
        "ID": 127,
        "name": "id Software",
        "slug": "id-software",
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 41
    }
}
"attachments": {
    "54344": {
        "ID": 54344,
        "URL": "",
        "guid": "",
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 843,
        "height": 499
    },
    "54345": {
        "ID": 54345,
        "URL": "",
        "guid": "",
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 1600
    }
}
```

}

Post.class:

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private int ID;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("content")
    private String content;

    @SerializedName("featured_image")
    private String featuredImage;

    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("URL")
    private String URL;

    @SerializedName("author")
    private Author author;

    @SerializedName("discussion")
    private Discussion discussion;

    @SerializedName("attachments")
    private Attachment attachments; // At this point I have problems
}
```

Attachment.class

```
public class Attachment {

    @SerializedName("URL")
    private String URL;

    @SerializedName("width")
    private int width;

    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height;
```

}

Everything works fine except the nested JSON objects in attachments or tags. The Attachment object does only contain default values and is not filled with the correct values from the JSON response.

My Retrofit builder:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(WordPressService.ENDPOINT)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(WordPressService.class);
```

I would like to have a list of attachment objects but I do not know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: obviously because `attachments` is not `Attachment` but rather associative array of Attachments

Comment: It is no array of Attachments, see JSON response

Comment: **associative** array from wiki *In computer science, an associative array, map, symbol table, or dictionary is an abstract data type composed of a **collection of (key, value) pairs**, such that each possible key appears at most once in the collection.*

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the assocative... I tried to use `private Map<String, List<Attachment>> attachments;` but then I get this error `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 53405 path $.posts[4].attachments`

Comment: @Selvin Thanks to your hint I found a solution. I needed to declare `private Map<String, Attachment> attachments;` Can you please post this as separate answer so that I can mark it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse the `attachments` and `tags` `JSON` elements use a `LinkedTreeMap`.

Update the `Post` class as follows:

```
public class Post {

  @SerializedName("ID")
  private int ID;

  @SerializedName("title")
  private String title;

  @SerializedName("content")
  private String content;

  @SerializedName("featured_image")
  private String featuredImage;

  @SerializedName("date")
  private String date;

  @SerializedName("URL")
  private String URL;

  @SerializedName("tags")
  LinkedTreeMap<String, Tag> tags;

  @SerializedName("attachments")
  LinkedTreeMap<String, Attachment> attachments;
}
```